Grafana alert no notification
When a Grafana alert fires and creates a notification, it works as expected. However, if the alert resolves and then fires again shortly after (within about 15 minutes), no new notification is created.
I suspect this is because of the group interval (default: 5 minutes). My understanding is that if a new alert occurs within the group interval after the previous one resolves, no notification is sent because the group remains active.
I noticed that there is no notification even after 5 min and when I setthe group interval to 1 second, the behavior does not change.
Has anyone experienced this or knows how it works?
